# Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS Screen Resolution

Tags: 18.04, screen, display-resolution

I recently got an old computer to install Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS on. I did and it worked at first, but it kept freezing and crashing.

I don't remember doing anything different, but it doesn't seem to freeze and crash anymore, but it's unusable because the screen resolution is so low.

My only option is 640x480. This is way too low. Nothing fits on the screen. In order to browse the web, I have to zoom out by 50% and it's just unbearable. I've tried every possible way to increase the screen resolution, but nothing works. The monitor supports up to 1680x1050.

The computer runs Windows 7 on a separate disk and Windows 7 works fine. For some reason, Ubuntu no longer works. I can not figure out why this is happening or how to fix it. I have tried `xrandr` and everything.

`lspci -v` output:

```
00:00.0 RAM memory: NVIDIA Corporation MCP61 Memory Controller (rev a1)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company MCP61 Memory Controller
    Flags: bus master, 66MHz, fast devsel, latency 0, NUMA node 0
    Capabilities: 

00:01.0 ISA bridge: NVIDIA Corporation MCP61 LPC Bridge (rev a2)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company MCP61 LPC Bridge
    Flags: bus master, 66MHz, fast devsel, latency 0, NUMA node 0
    I/O ports at 4f00 [size=256]

00:01.1 SMBus: NVIDIA Corporation MCP61 SMBus (rev a2)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company MCP61 SMBus
    Flags: 66MHz, fast devsel, IRQ 11, NUMA node 0
    I/O ports at 4900 [size=64]
    I/O ports at 4d00 [size=64]
    I/O ports at 4e00 [size=64]
    Capabilities: 
    Kernel driver in use: nForce2_smbus
    Kernel modules: i2c_nforce2

00:01.2 RAM memory: NVIDIA Corporation MCP61 Memory Controller (rev a2)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company MCP61 Memory Controller
    Flags: 66MHz, fast devsel, NUMA node 0

00:02.0 USB controller: NVIDIA Corporation MCP61 USB 1.1 Controller (rev a3) (prog-if 10 [OHCI])
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company MCP61 USB 1.1 Controller
    Flags: bus master, 66MHz, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 23, NUMA node 0
    Memory at fbfff000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
    Capabilities: 
    Kernel driver in use: ohci-pci

00:02.1 USB controller: NVIDIA Corporation MCP61 USB 2.0 Controller (rev a3) (prog-if 20 [EHCI])
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company MCP61 USB 2.0 Controller
    Flags: bus master, 66MHz, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 22, NUMA node 0
    Memory at fbffec00 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=256]
    Capabilities: 
    Kernel driver in use: ehci-pci

00:04.0 PCI bridge: NVIDIA Corporation MCP61 PCI bridge (rev a1) (prog-if 01 [Subtractive decode])
    Flags: bus master, 66MHz, fast devsel, latency 0, NUMA node 0
    Bus: primary=00, secondary=01, subordinate=01, sec-latency=64
    Capabilities: 

00:05.0 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation MCP61 High Definition Audio (rev a2)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company MCP61 High Definition Audio
    Flags: bus master, 66MHz, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 22, NUMA node 0
    Memory at fbff8000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: 
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
    Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel

00:07.0 Bridge: NVIDIA Corporation MCP61 Ethernet (rev a2)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company MCP61 Ethernet
    Flags: bus master, 66MHz, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 24, NUMA node 0
    Memory at fbffd000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
    I/O ports at e480 [size=8]
    Capabilities: 
    Kernel driver in use: forcedeth
    Kernel modules: forcedeth

00:08.0 IDE interface: NVIDIA Corporation MCP61 SATA Controller (rev a2) (prog-if 85 [PCI native mode-only controller, supports bus mastering])
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company MCP61 SATA Controller
    Flags: bus master, 66MHz, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 21, NUMA node 0
    I/O ports at e400 [size=8]
    I/O ports at e080 [size=4]
    I/O ports at e000 [size=8]
    I/O ports at dc00 [size=4]
    I/O ports at d880 [size=16]
    Memory at fbffc000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
    Capabilities: 
    Kernel driver in use: sata_nv
    Kernel modules: sata_nv, pata_acpi

00:08.1 IDE interface: NVIDIA Corporation MCP61 SATA Controller (rev a2) (prog-if 85 [PCI native mode-only controller, supports bus mastering])
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company MCP61 SATA Controller
    Flags: bus master, 66MHz, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 23, NUMA node 0
    I/O ports at d800 [size=8]
    I/O ports at d480 [size=4]
    I/O ports at d400 [size=8]
    I/O ports at d080 [size=4]
    I/O ports at d000 [size=16]
    Memory at fbff3000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
    Capabilities: 
    Kernel driver in use: sata_nv
    Kernel modules: sata_nv, pata_acpi

00:09.0 PCI bridge: NVIDIA Corporation MCP61 PCI Express bridge (rev a2) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, NUMA node 0
    Bus: primary=00, secondary=02, subordinate=02, sec-latency=0
    Capabilities: 
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport

00:0b.0 PCI bridge: NVIDIA Corporation MCP61 PCI Express bridge (rev a2) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, NUMA node 0
    Bus: primary=00, secondary=03, subordinate=03, sec-latency=0
    Capabilities: 
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport

00:0c.0 PCI bridge: NVIDIA Corporation MCP61 PCI Express bridge (rev a2) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, NUMA node 0
    Bus: primary=00, secondary=04, subordinate=04, sec-latency=0
    Capabilities: 
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport

00:0d.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation C61 [GeForce 6150SE nForce 430] (rev a2) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company C61 [GeForce 6150SE nForce 430]
    Flags: bus master, 66MHz, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 10, NUMA node 0
    Memory at fa000000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16M]
    Memory at e0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
    Memory at f9000000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16M]
    Expansion ROM at 000c0000 [disabled] [size=128K]
    Capabilities: 
    Kernel modules: nvidiafb, nouveau

00:18.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 10h Processor HyperTransport Configuration
    Flags: fast devsel, NUMA node 0
    Capabilities: 

00:18.1 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 10h Processor Address Map
    Flags: fast devsel, NUMA node 0

00:18.2 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 10h Processor DRAM Controller
    Flags: fast devsel, NUMA node 0

00:18.3 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 10h Processor Miscellaneous Control
    Flags: fast devsel, NUMA node 0
    Capabilities: 
    Kernel driver in use: k10temp
    Kernel modules: k10temp

00:18.4 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 10h Processor Link Control
    Flags: fast devsel, NUMA node 0
```

Comment: As this might be GPU related, please add output from `lspci -v` command, you can show us only lines related to your VGA device (graphics card).

Comment: Show me `grep -i nomodeset /etc/default/grub`. Start comments to me with @heynnema or I may miss them.

Comment: @Comar what do I look for in the output of lspci -v? It's too big to copy and paste it in here.

Comment: @heynnema I ran the grep command, but it didn't find anything

Comment: Have you installed the appropriate Nvidia video driver? In the `Software & Updates` app, `Additional Drivers` tab, tell me what you see.

Comment: @heynnema Thanks for all of the help. I've been wanting to get a new GPU anyway, so I finally did, and so far it works fine with the new GPU. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

You can reinstall the driver with the command sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall.  then reboot, then change the resolution.  if not, please see this website

[How do I install additional drivers?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/47506/how-do-i-install-additional-drivers)

Maybe it work.. :)

Comment: Thanks for all of the help. I've been wanting to get a new GPU anyway, so I finally did, and so far it works fine with the new GPU. Thanks again